# How to generate a list of given length in Java 8?

Tags: java, python, java-8

I want to create a list (or collection in general) by calling a method x times. In Python it would be something like this.

```
self.generated = [self.generate() for _ in range(length)]
```

I tried to code something similar in JDK 8.

```
this.generated = IntStream.range(0, length)
                          .mapToObj(n -> this.generate())
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It works, but somehow it doesn't feel allright. Is there a more proper way of doing it?

Comment: The two python code snaps are not equivalent, one is replicating the same reference `length` times, the other is creating `length` objects (assuming `generate()` creates a new object for each invokation)

Comment: Yes, it's true if self.generate is returning references. Initially, it has been returning floats, making the snippets equivalent. Still, it's the first case I'm interested in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not Python developer so I may misunderstood your example, but judging from Java example you may be looking for something like

```
Stream.generate(this::generate).limit(length).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But as [Brian Goetz mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748612/how-to-generate-a-list-of-given-length-in-java-8#comment36524014_23748739) your approach

```
IntStream.range(0, length).mapToObj(i->...)
```

will perform significantly better in parallel.

Comment: Both this and the range-oriented one will do the job.  However, the range-oriented one will perform significantly better in parallel.

Comment: What if this::generate required an argument? That's my case.

Comment: Got it!         Stream.generate(() -> client.createInventory(new RandomInventory())).limit(10).collect(toSet());

Comment: @Pshemo I got that -- just wasn't sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this would feel any better to you, but here's one way to get the same effect:

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[length];
Arrays.setAll(arr, n -> this.generate());
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(arr);
```