# Array generated by a method

Tags: java, arrays, coding-style

How can I generate an array of specified length by a method?

In short, what's an elegant replacement of this code:

```
Result generate() {
    // logic
}

Result[] results(int length) {
    Result[] results = new Result[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) results[i] = generate();
    return results;
}
```

Comment: What you don't like in this solution? Pretty and neat.

Comment: With Java 8 : `return IntStream.range(0, length).mapToObj(i -> generate()).toArray(Result[]::new);`. Whether it is more readable/elegant or not is up to the reader.

Comment: @david.lucky I was looking for exactly what has Pshemo posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Java 8 instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) results[i] = generate();
```

you can use

```
Arrays.setAll(results, i -> generate());
```

You can also remove explicitly generating `new Result[length]` and let it be handled by stream

```
return IntStream.range(0, length).mapToObj(i->generate()).toArray(Result[]::new);
```

or probably more readable (but as [Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz) mentioned: with [worse parallel performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748612/how-to-generate-a-list-of-given-length-in-java-8/23748739#comment36524014_23748739) compared to `range` version)

```
return Stream.generate(this::generate).limit(length).toArray(Result[]::new);
```

---

But don't confuse `setAll(array, generator)` with `fill(array, element)` method. `fill` will fill entire array with single element you passed while `setAll` will use generator to generate new element for each index in array.

Example:

```
static AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();
static int generate() {
    return ai.incrementAndGet();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] result = new int[10];
    Arrays.fill(result, generate());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

    Arrays.setAll(result, i->generate());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

}
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Comment: Your first suggestion is the best, in my opinion.

Comment: @RedRoboHood I also like it, but I am not sure what approach OP is looking for so I added few more options.